# jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'dict object' has no attribute 'imageLinks'

Tags: python, json, flask

This is my code, who calls error:

```
    {% extends "add_book_header.html" %}


{% block content %}
    {% if books %}
        <p>Results: {{ books|length }}</p>
        {% for book in books %}
            <div class="card h-100">
                <img src={{book["volumeInfo"]["imageLinks"]["smallThumbnail"]}} class="card-img-top">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">{{ book["volumeInfo"]["title"]}}</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">descripthion</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">link</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

and this is structure of book

```
    {
      "kind": "books#volume",
      "id": "NwxaDwAAQBAJ",
      "etag": "guYzwBLXoHI",
      "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/NwxaDwAAQBAJ",
      "volumeInfo": {
        "title": "Цельная жизнь. Главные навыки для достижения ваших целей",
        "authors": [
          "Джек Кэнфилд",
          "Марк Виктор Хансен",
          "Лес Хьюитт"
        ],
        "publisher": "Litres",
        "publishedDate": "2020-01-31",
        "description": "Основная причина, по которой у большинства из нас не ладятся дела, – расфокусированность. Мы отвлекаемся от выбранного курса, откладываем важное на потом и в итоге под разными предлогами отказываемся от достижения цели. Авторы «Цельной жизни» предлагают 10 ключевых стратегий, которые помогут сосредоточиться на главном и добиться своего. Эта книга, проданная общим тиражом 600 000 экземпляров, выдержала десять переизданий на английском языке и сейчас переживает второе рождение на русском. Ранее она выходила в сокращенной и заметно переработанной версии. Новый вариант максимально приближен к оригиналу. Он дополнен вдохновляющими историями и техниками, не вошедшими в предыдущее издание.",
        "industryIdentifiers": [
          {
            "type": "ISBN_10",
            "identifier": "5041133891",
          },
          {
            "type": "ISBN_13",
            "identifier": "9785041133894",
          }
        ],
        "readingModes": {
          "text": true,
          "image": true,
        },
        "pageCount": 505,
        "printedPageCount": 505,
        "printType"
        "categories": [
          "Psychology / Education & Training",
          "Psychology / General"
        ],
        "averageRating": 5.0,
        "ratingsCount": 1,
        "maturityRating": "NOT_MATURE",
        "allowAnonLogging": true,
        "contentVersion": "1.3.3.0.preview.3",
        "panelizationSummary": {
          "containsEpubBubbles": false,
          "containsImageBubbles": false,
        },
        "imageLinks": {
          "smallThumbnail": "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=NwxaDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&edge=curl&imgtk=AFLRE71lKFAeu_Yn1NL-co5ed48HedO9HKLjSDYj5gwf_QXOxKOLmwtML58eByCk-KumaPbqi-mPCm2Hvabhyrqc0k2s_m7PlyLgMYTEiph1MCTSO7h7FqS0au_KU3uAQeVAGmWdx_Qm&source=gbs_api",
          "thumbnail": "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=NwxaDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&imgtk=AFLRE73fv48xV0IazZs8xkdh4eWP4wIUmPjAze160rGEe2Djr5QGlUtqsQdLe6rYvlavPDrzy8N2x53TImANJyv-rF6vztH1HN82c8kpUr090UPlncObSAUL0_g-mrY02jvUF2VHv_LS&source=gbs_api",
          "small": "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=NwxaDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=2&edge=curl&imgtk=AFLRE71W89k5GICHa60oHUhVkFn2TQb0mf2BT8sV4UJE4rQEHPrg8gi7ocADy2d17h1hzVttahG5_dZebwBMYky9sM5LGXZk5pFsR3an20nZqyL5qFx9tMe2IjYdiZA51nRxP9qErsgp&source=gbs_api",
          "medium": "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=NwxaDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=3&edge=curl&imgtk=AFLRE72KZCR3kxHuC7Wwv7dfjJYNcgSoep9eXMRzRTPPPdspCUrX7d9ySFWxLDnBoxT8mZPQfjPwiZbepP2ms8J5bKam3aYOfxwnvW3ngqlMIYGYciXeizspZIvhEdfqGrUFTPXuvxhV&source=gbs_api",
          "large": "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=NwxaDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=4&edge=curl&imgtk=AFLRE70VGEvMyFnUkpl-uvwjWHDLZtKXoN766b0Ue5vB48hug5kPIzGvVmrrhxKbShuRLT2gQo3ZB_jiuN3ENFBOXDDXllsWG2p4TGVF9nEax1sEgpTxG8HWqeHi15lVvYTPrqU7RRBv&source=gbs_api",
          "extraLarge": "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=NwxaDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=6&edge=curl&imgtk=AFLRE71SsWc6rXWi-38mNgkbJI36hzGlHxqvQBJBQQPQsCg9iFX7g-lOpTk4NZNqjxPwtdSApWp8unszC5R5hhbHKWDbLkewsXEPpWPLLZmka8RVv3_HPBWANHDASHyiYjKRfeyFV59i&source=gbs_api",
        },
        "language": "ru",
        "previewLink": "http://books.google.ru/books?id=NwxaDwAAQBAJ&hl=&source=gbs_api",
        "infoLink": "https://play.google.com/store/books/details?id=NwxaDwAAQBAJ&source=gbs_api",
        "canonicalVolumeLink": "https://play.google.com/store/books/details?id=NwxaDwAAQBAJ",
      },
      "layerInfo": {
        "layers": [
          {
            "layerId": "geo",
            "volumeAnnotationsVersion": "5",
          }
        ],
      },
      "saleInfo": {
        "country": "RU",
        "saleability": "NOT_FOR_SALE",
        "isEbook": false,
      },
      "accessInfo": {
        "country": "RU",
        "viewability": "PARTIAL",
        "embeddable": true,
        "publicDomain": false,
        "textToSpeechPermission": "ALLOWED",
        "epub": {
          "isAvailable": true,
          "acsTokenLink": "http://books.google.ru/books/download/%D0%A6%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8C_%D0%93%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-sample-epub.acsm?id=NwxaDwAAQBAJ&format=epub&output=acs4_fulfillment_token&dl_type=sample&source=gbs_api",
        },
        "pdf": {
          "isAvailable": true,
          "acsTokenLink": "http://books.google.ru/books/download/%D0%A6%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8C_%D0%93%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-sample-pdf.acsm?id=NwxaDwAAQBAJ&format=pdf&output=acs4_fulfillment_token&dl_type=sample&source=gbs_api",
        },
        "webReaderLink": "http://play.google.com/books/reader?id=NwxaDwAAQBAJ&hl=&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_api",
        "accessViewStatus": "SAMPLE",
        "quoteSharingAllowed": false,
      },
    }
```

You can trust me, all keys are right. And this is my error:

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'dict object' has no attribute 'imageLinks'
```

I have done many solution for this error, which I have found. But anything didn't work. Including it:

```
{% set img = book["volumeInfo"]["imageLinks"] %}
        ...
        <img src={{img["smallThumbnail"]}} class="card-img-top">
```

a first string worked good, but second was calling error. Please, I need your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Privet Vladimir,
I saw your comment on my first answer and deleted the first answer.
Seems the inner dictionary inside the Jinja object is not being parsed correctly, but I cannot reproduce your bug on my computer. Maybe there are too many levels of nesting.
One thing I have had to correct to make it work on my computer are those weird true or false that appear in the response without quotes or capital letters. Maybe this is a side-effect of this problem.
Another option I can imagine, is parsing the response from googleapis first in your controller and build a book object with all needed fields at first level and then pass this book object to the jinja template.
Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you very much :) Yes, bug arise on third level of nesting. I will try fix it in controller

Answer (score 2):

You did not consider the items keys inside your book object

```
{% block content %}
    {% if books %}
        <p>Results: {{ books|length }}</p>
        {% for book in books %}
            <div class="card h-100">
              {% for item in book['items'] %}
                <img src={{item["volumeInfo"]["imageLinks"]["smallThumbnail"]}} class="card-img-top">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">{{ item["volumeInfo"]["title"]}}</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">descripthion</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">link</a>
                </div>
             {% endfor %}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You always have to access in jinja  by using `"."` like :-

```
{{book["volumeInfo"].imageLinks.smallThumbnail"}}
```

if its array use `''`, and if its nested object use `.`
but if you want to use in .py file use `''` one.